# Cannot find module 'utils/notification' in react ssr

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

```
import './App.css';
import Router from './router/Router';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am going to make a previous create-react-app project to SSR react app.
In my previous project, I used absolute path for importing files.
After changing previous project to SSR, can't import some files.
What is solution?